# Read specific part of a data in R

Tags: r

I have this code here:

```
library(BCEA)
data(Vaccine)
ls()
```

Now, i get this:

```
 [1] "c"             "cost.GP"       "cost.hosp"     "cost.otc"      "cost.time.off" "cost.time.vac"
 [7] "cost.travel"   "cost.trt1"     "cost.trt2"     "cost.vac"      "e"             "N"            
[13] "N.outcomes"    "N.resources"   "QALYs.adv"     "QALYs.death"   "QALYs.hosp"    "QALYs.inf"    
[19] "QALYs.pne"     "treats"
```

How can i access the 'c' value?
Something like Vaccine(c)?
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the given data `Vaccine`, each one of `"c", "cost.GP", ...` corresponds to separate data.
So, when you load the data of `Vaccine` into current workspace by `data(Vaccine)`, you can directly access each of the 20 listed data values.
For example,

```
> head(c)
     Status Quo Vaccination
[1,]  10.409146   16.252537
[2,]   5.834875    9.373437
[3,]   5.784903   15.935623
[4,]  12.208484   18.654250
[5,]   9.786787   16.467321
[6,]   6.560276    9.689887
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
Please i have just one other question.
Suppose i need to create my own c vector, and suppose i have this vector names A with 6 numbers and this Vector named B with other 6 numbers, how can i combine them so i get the above matrix?

It would be like having Status Quo and Vaccination separated

Comment: look into `?cbind` of R

Answer (score 0):

Just like this:

```
c
```

It's a named object, so type "c" at the prompt, press return, or use directly in any function within this environment